# PLL phase frequency detector

Tags: pll, phase

If there is a constant phase difference  between the VCO signal and reference signal, the phase frequency detector will always givr an error signal.  How can the PLL lock in this condition?

I mean the VCO can only change its frequency and there is no parameter in a VCO for phase change.

Changing frequency in this condition will never lock the PLL.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The question lacks detail, but I’ll try to help.  A PLL will only link when the frequency is correct and the phase is correct (what counts as ‘correct’ depends on the design and configuration of the device) so if the frequency is correct but the phase is incorrect the PLL will allow itself to drift slightly until the phase is correct.  Does that help?

Comment: yes , thank you  ,

Comment: but how pll drift to adapt the phase ? I know block diagram of pll and I didn't see that option ?

Comment: @frog I didn't see this option in any pll diagram,

Comment: simply because nothing is ‘locking’ the PLL, it will never perfectly match the desired frequency while it’s not locked, so will eventually drift one way or the other

Comment: No separate control for phase is required. Frequency and phase are intimately related -- phase is simply the integral of frequency over time. You can't change one without affecting the other, and the same input to the VCO controls both. Think of it this way: If the frequency is very nearly correct, the phase will be slowly drifting. The PLL will "lock" (the error signal will stop changing) only when both frequency and phase are correct.

Comment: @DaveTweed I admit to *automatically* regard a **VCO** as an oscillator whose frequency is voltage-controlled, because these kind of modules are ubiquitous. Most PLLs arrange the feedback loop to accommodate the integration that this kind of VCO inherently has. I've done software PLLs which use a fixed-frequency oscillator - phase changes are added/subtracted at intervals to maintain phase lock - I'd hesitate to equate this to a "conventional" VCO. This software PLL oscillator does track reference oscillator, but perhaps you can view the *integrator* as elsewhere?

Comment: @glen_geek: I too have done true digital PLLs on a number of projects (both software and FPGA), but I always use an NCO (numerically controlled oscillator) to replace the analog VCO. An NCO literally adds the frequency control word repeatedly to an accumulator, whose output bits represent the phase of the oscillator -- a direct implementation of the integrator concept.

Answer (score 2):

Understand the relationship between phase and frequency.

If you have two signals of slightly different frequency, the phase is forever rotating between them.

Say the signal edges line up at t=0.  And say they are 1kHz and 1.01kHz.
After 1ms (1 cycle), the 1.01kHz signal will be leading by (1 - 1.01) / (1) = 1%, or 3.6°.
After 10ms, it will be leading by 36°.
After 100ms, it will be leading by 356.4°.
After 101ms, the edges coincide again, and the process repeats.

Phase is adjusted simply by nudging the VCO up and down a little bit. Mathematically, we say that phase is the integral of frequency difference.  Using a control loop to force that integral to zero, doesn't just ensure the frequencies match closely -- it's a perfect integrator* by definition, so if it's locked at all, the frequency *must* be exact!

*Unlike an op-amp voltage integrator for example, which still has finite gain at DC.

Answer (score 1):

When in a nearly locked condition , a PLL changes the oscillator *frequency* slightly when a *phase difference* is detected. This means that the frequency will become only stationary if the phase is matched.

$$\frac{df}{dt}\propto\Delta \phi$$

Answer (score 1):

You’re missing a key relationship between the phase and frequency:

**Frequency is the rate (time derivative) of phase change**.

Conversely,

**Phase is the time integral of frequency**.

You change one, you always affect the other. By changing the VCO frequency, you can get any frequency at any phase you need. That’s from basic theorems in calculus.

Both involve a constant scaling factor (multiplier). The multiplier is 1 for angular frequency. For frequency in Hz, it \$1/(2\pi)\$ for frequency derived from phase change rate, and \$2\pi\$ for phase derived from integral of frequency in Hz.

Answer (score 0):

The error voltage from the phase detector goes through a low-pass filter to the voltage-controlled oscillator.  The oscillator frequency varies according to the error voltage, and "settles down" to zero frequency and zero phase error, as defined by the design of the phase detector.  Some PD designs go for zero phase error, some go for 90 degree offset.  The key is that the PD output voltage is what controls the VCO frequency, and hence the phase offset.